# ASP conundrum (how to resolve)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

Okay, so I'm using validation controls on a website

At first I was getting the classic error

```
 WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).
```

Didn't take much to fix that.

I added the following to my web.config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="none"/>
</appSettings>
```

However, now when I run my pages, my asp:LinkButtons don't work correctly, their code-behind doesn't seem to execute (it's a school assignment so I can merely alter them to anchors. Guidelines mandate asp:LinkButtons).

I tried

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms"/>
</appSettings>
```

But then I get the old error and my page won't load.

:/ I'm very confounded. What can I do?

EDIT: something possibly worth noting

My asp linkbuttons only malfunction in pages that also possess asp validators.
My other pages with asp link buttons work just fine.

Comment: Check your web browser's javascript console output for any script errors during the page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this informative post from the [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pranav_rastogi/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms/)

Add the following to your Global.asax file at the root of your web project:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "1.7.1"; //Change to the version of jQuery you require
    ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jquery", new ScriptResourceDefinition
    {
        Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + str + ".min.js", 
        DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-" + str + ".js", 
        CdnPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + str + ".min.js", 
        CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-" + str + ".js", 
        CdnSupportsSecureConnection = true, 
        LoadSuccessExpression = "window.jQuery"
    });
}
```

Place the following in your Master page or on each page that uses the validation controls:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Hallejuah! Ur sew gud!